# Show that there can't exists $P,Q \in M^{n \times n}(A)$ (ring of matrices over commutative ring $A$) such that $PQ - QP = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

Show that there can't exists $P,Q \in M^{n \times n}(A)$ (ring of matrices over commutative ring $A$) such that $PQ - QP = I$ (the identity).

I thought my solution came too easily, so I wanted a little help to check to see.

Suppose that $PQ - QP = I$, then $PQ = I + QP$, and $Tr(PQ)=Tr(I+QP)$. Now, let's let $p_{ij}$ and $q_{ij}$ but the element $i,j$ of $P$ and $Q$ respectively.

$$Tr(PQ)=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n p_{jk}q_{kj} = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n q_{kj}p_{jk} = Tr(QP)$$
$$Tr(I+QP)=\sum_{j=1}^n \left ( \left ( \sum_{k=1}^n p_{jk}q_{kj} \right ) + 1 \right ) = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n p_{jk}q_{kj}  + \sum_{j=1}^n1$$

Where all the sums happen in the ring $A$. This is just the linear property of the trace. So by the properties of the ring operations, we can see that 
$$Tr(PQ) = Tr(I+PQ) \iff Tr(PQ) - Tr(QP) = Tr(I) \iff 0 = Tr(I)$$

To me, this seems like the contradiction. However, I am just thinking that if the communicative ring $A$ is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, then $\sum^n1=0$. So while the property that $0=Tr(I)$ is not true in general, there does seem to be this special case where it is true.

Comment: You're right. Take $P =  \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$ and $Q = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right) $, $A = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. $PQ - QP = I_{2}$.

Comment: As you've (more or less) discovered, $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$ is a very useful fact to have in your mathematical backpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be solutions to this where the characteristic divides $n$.

For instance if
$$P=\pmatrix{0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\1&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\0&2&0&\cdots&0&0
\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&n-1&0}$$
and
$$Q=\pmatrix{0&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\0&0&1&\cdots&0&0\\0&0&0&\cdots&0&0
\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots
\\0&0&0&0&\cdots&1
\\1&0&0&\cdots&0&0}$$
then $QP-PQ=I$ in characteristic $n$.